# upgrading spring-boot plugin and replacing BootRepackage

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have a Boot application. It generates two artifacts: admin, and worker.

Under Boot 1.4.x, I had a task like :

`task adminBoot(type: BootRepackage, dependsOn: adminJar) {`

It generated the fat jar for admin, and I depended on this task on my docker task. Note that I needed it named so that I could create two artifacts.

Upgrading to boot 2.0.2, I noticed that `BootRepackage` is renamed to `bootJar` and `bootWar`. But I cannot make it work

`task adminBoot(type: BootJar, dependsOn: adminJar) {`

gives me an error

> Could not get unknown property 'BootJar' for root project 'XXX' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

And this

`task adminBoot(type: bootJar, dependsOn: adminJar) {`

Give me

> rg.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootJar_Decorated cannot be cast to java.lang.Class

What is the proper name to create a task of bootJar?

Comment: What is the task type of `bootJar`?

Comment: I guess that is what I am looking for.

Comment: Have you tried importing this class: org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootJar

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue? I am facing a similar error while creating 2 artifacts and defining type as BootJar.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the full path of the class...

Like this...

```
task bootJarApp(type:org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootJar)
```